# Function.prototype.bind() alternative in C (not C++)

Tags: c, function-pointers

In my C program, I need to pass a callback function to a 3rd party library. The library calls this callback with a few arguments. However, I need to expose one more variable to this callback. This variable is accessible in the scope of the function from within I'm setting the callback.

In JS, I'd easily solve this with `.bind()`, more or less like this (pseudocode):

```
func my_callback(int a, int b) {
    printf("A: %d\n", a);
    printf("B: %d\n", b);
}

func new_instance() {
    int a = 1;

    // setup_callback expects (void(*)(int b)) as an argument
    setup_callback(my_callback.bind(null, a));
}
```

There are two main restrictions:

1. Variable `a` cannot be global - it is declared and initialized inside the `new_instance` procedure.
2. It has to be a C solution (ideally ANSI), not C++.

After playing with it (function pointers) for a while, I don't seem to be any closer to a workable solution...

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible without some kind of global state. Or you will have to write different callback functions for each possible value of `a` (if feasible)

Comment: Where do the parameters to the callback originate? I.e. within the library, or passed to the library or might they be values that you pass to the library at some point? If the latter, that might be exploited in some cases.

Comment: Without exploiting some pass-through parameter, I'll echo @EugeneSh. that a global (or file static) variable would be needed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah, I suspected... well, so it's back to the drawing board, never mind.. :D

Comment: @AviBerger the one I need to add originates in the function (my function - the one in which the callback is set up) and the others originate in the library itself (that's the problem, some of them come from the lib and some in my code). Unfortunately I can't edit the library itself, because it's actually a shared library..

Comment: Alright, I'll use a global state (single instance solution) and deal with multi-instance use cases some time later 
Thanks for your help 

Comment: What are the callback arguments?  Is one of them a user-defined pointer (usually a `void *`) to some state that you provide: `int callback(int a, char *b, double c, void *context)` where you can specify the `context` to be given to the callback function (such as `void set_callback(int (*callback)(int a, char *b, double c, void *context), void *context)`)?  If so, then you solve the problem by passing a suitable pointer to the extra information, or a pointer to a structure which contains the extra information.  If you don't have an option like that, you probably cannot resolve the problem.

Comment: Actually, I should say "you cannot resolve the problem without providing the callback function with access to a file scope variable that contains, or points to, the extra information it needs".  It's not nice to have to do that, but sometimes it is necessary.  If possible, make the file scope variable `static` so it is not visible outside the module that defines the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a closure, and closures are not a feature of the C language.  Since you're not in control of the callback-using API, there is no workaround to allow you to get an additional local variable through to the callback.

If you *were* in control of the API, then it would be possible to make the callback interface accept an additional parameter along with the function, to be stored alongside it and be passed to it as an argument when the function is called.  Typically a parameter of type `void *` is used for such a purpose, as you can convey data of any type that way.

Even then, however, you need to be careful.  You could provide the *value* of a local variable that way, but if you provided a *pointer to* a local variable then that would only be usable during the lifetime of that variable, which is not longer than the execution of the function containing it (and would be shorter under some circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

C does not support that, period. What can be done instead is to store the "bound" variable in a scope accessible to the callback and expose it to the code that would create the closure were it's available.

It has the drawbacks of storing state, thus it might get messy when sharing data e.g. in multithreaded contexts.

Should it suffice? Depends on context, but bear in mind this is no function object by any means, it is merely a stored state.
Can it be improved? Depends, but if the `b` parameter passed by the API using the callback can utilized to somehow identify its caller, then maybe some container of such callback states can be created to separate them from each other.

The dead-simple solution would be sth like this. Again, I cannot tell it this suffices or not.

```c
/* callback.c */
#include "callback.h"
static int first_arg;

/* May or may not be static.
   I chose static for simplicity...
*/
static void my_callback(int a, int b)
{
/* whatever */
}

void api_compliant_callback(int b)
{
  my_callback(first_arg, b);
}

void set_first_arg(int val)
{
  first_arg = val;
}
```

```c
/* callback.h */
#ifndef CALLBACK_H
#define CALLBACK_H

void set_first_arg(int);
void api_compliant_callback(int);

#endif /* CALLBACK_H */
```

```c
/* file where the callbacks are registered */
#include "callback.h"

void fkn()
{
  /* whatever */
  set_first_arg(42);
  setup_callback(api_compliant_callback);

  /* anything that goes after */
}
```